# MATH? SHA256 Roulette / Lottery computable?

Tags: math, random, repeat, sha256, seed

There is a website where you can play roulette, you can put on the colors only (red, black = double, green = 14x)

The rolls are computed by the following way:

There is a serverSeed EVERY 24 hours its different
This is a precomputed value generated some time in the past.
Seeds are generated in a chain such that today's seed is the hash of tomorrow's seed. Since there is no way to reverse SHA-256 we can prove each seed was generated in advance by working backwards from a precomputed chain.

There is a lotto and round_id too but they are given only the serverSeed is hidden until next day.

Example:

```
$server_seed = "39b7d32fcb743c244c569a56d6de4dc27577d6277d6cf155bdcba6d05befcb34";
$lotto = "0422262831";
$round_id = "1";
$hash = hash("sha256",$server_seed."-".$lotto."-".$round_id);
$roll = hexdec(substr($hash,0,8)) % 15;
echo "Round $round_id = $roll";
```

This is how rolls are generated with making a new hash everyround as the round ID increments by 1 every roll, the serverSeed and the lotto remains the same whole day.

There is also a history page on the website where you can check every rolled color and number in the past.

My Question: Is there anyway to compute the next roll by the already rolled numbers? (I dont talk about reversing the SHA256 serverSeed or anything like that!!!)

But really isnt any math in this?

I know its MIGHT be all random but i cant imagine this is random.

Here are the yesterday's rolls where you can see the Round IDs too.

I saw the rolls a lot of time repeat sometimes but sometimes its not... I cant believe it doesnt have any math in it.

[>>>> LUCK? OR MATH? <<<<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9Vzl.png)

Waiting for answers...

Answer (score 0):

The method is an example of "KDF in Counter Mode" as defined in [NIST SP 800-108](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-108/sp800-108.pdf), with SHA256 as "PRF". As far as i know this method is considered a secure random number generator. So the answer is "There is no math in it, repetitions are just luck".